# How to pick words from a string that matches a criteria

Tags: python, string

I have one string containing many words, I want to store all the words that start with `a` in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be easier if first we turn the string into a list of words.

```py
words = s.split()
```

We'll make a new list called `a_words` which contains all the words that start with 'a'

```py
a_words = []
for word in words:
    if word[0].lower() == 'a':
        a_words.append(word)
```

And now we're done, but this can be simplified

```py
words = s.split()
a_words = filter(lambda word: word[0].lower() == 'a', words)
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
yourlist = [word for word in yourstring.split() if word.startswith("a")]
```

Comment: This will not work as it will not append the word in the list but only the letter `a`.

Comment: @Aditya This will work.  Did you actually try it?

Comment: @Aditya, it will work 100%.

Comment: @Aditya, it works just fine (I even verified it). Do you know what this list comprehension does? I think you're misinterpreting it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit more complicated than the other answers, but this works as well.

```
text = "Happy Ape comes around"
list = []

for i in text.split():
    x = i.lower()
    if x.startswith("a"):
        list.append(i)

print(list)
```

**Output:** ['Ape', 'around']

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look to Regular Expressions (RE) module.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

The method `re.findall(...)` will find all the expressions matching the regex and return a list of them.

```py
import re

string = "Ah, this is an absolutely amazing example"
re.findall('(?:\s|^)((?=a|A)\w*)', string)
# -> ["Ah", "an", "absolutely", "amazing"]
```

Here you select any word starting with 'a' or 'A'.
Explanation :

- `(?:\s|^)` :

  - `(?:` non selective group
  - `\s` Any space or tab char
  - `|` & `^`  or start of string
- `((?=a|A)\w*)`

  - `(?=a|A)` Non selective group for 'a' or 'A'
  - `\w*` any word character at least zero times
  - `(` & `)` selective group, that will be the returned string.

**--EDIT--**
After a quick benchmark test, the RegEx method seems actually slower than the Filter method proposed by @Botahamec

```py
def regex_method(s):
     start = timer()
     re.findall('(?:\s|^)((?=a|A)\w*)', s)
     end = timer()
     return( timedelta(seconds=end-start) )

def filter_method(s):
     start = timer()
     words = s.split()
     a_words = filter(lambda word: word[0].lower() == 'a', words)
     end = timer()
     return( timedelta(seconds=end-start) )

len(s)
# -> 27000000

print(regex_method(s))
# -> 0:00:01.231664
print(filter_method(s))
# -> 0:00:00.759951
```

Comment: Next time, could you please finish your answer before you post it?

Comment: You don't need to add the space and parentheses to the regular expression. `'a\w+'` will work just fine and will find matching words at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: @cesarv No you would also match the "ample" from "example".

Comment: @vinalti, you're right! The correct regex would be `r'\ba\w+\b'`.

Comment: @cesarv   I corrected the regex, I found the real one, tell me what you think :)  -- Aditya can you reconsider this answer ? I think that's much more efficient and elegant than creating a loop. -- Wait, after testing, it seems having issues with python, i'll fix it

Comment: Ok that seems to work good, `s = "Ah, this is an absolutely amazing example"`  `re.findall('(?:\s|^)((?=a|A)\w*)', s)`
-> `['Ah', 'an', 'absolutely', 'amazing']`

Comment: @vinalti, it works but goes against one of Python's principles: simple is better than complex.. :)

Comment: @cesarv Yes, and if you check now, I made a benchmark and it is actually slower, so... My Bad ! ^^